# Array call CollectionView - Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to show these array types in a collectionView. When I print article.baslik, the output I got was [["2020-02-25 22:09"], ["2020-04-25 22:09"], ["2020-04-25 22:09"]]. I want to show the array inside Array. It now shows the contents of the whole array. I want to print 2020-02-25 22:09 on 1.labelText, 2020-04-25 22:09 on 2.labelText, 2020-04-25 22:09 on 3.labelText. The output I currently get in labelText is all of Array [["2020-02-25 22:09"], ["2020-04-25 22:09"], ["2020-04-25 22:09" ]]

To summarize, I throw the data I have drawn from the database more than once into the "formDate" variable. I add this variable to the date in the structure of detailTaxItem. I want to synchronize this date data with collectionView to altPriceLabel.text.

```
struct detayTaxItem {
    var aciklama : String
    var baslik : String
    var fiyat : String
    var adet : String
    var tarih : String

    init (aciklama : String, baslik : String, fiyat : String,adet : String,tarih : String) {
        self.aciklama = aciklama
        self.baslik = baslik
        self.fiyat = fiyat
        self.adet = adet
        self.tarih = tarih
       }
}
class TaxTableViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    var items : [detayTaxItem] = []

 @objc func veriyerlestir(){


            let newitem = detayTaxItem(aciklama:"\(String(describing: self.formAdıSoyadı))", baslik: "", fiyat: "\(String(describing: self.formFiyat))", adet: "", tarih: "\(String(describing: self.formTARIH))")

                  self.items.append(newitem)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.collectionView.reloadData()

        }
    }

  @objc func restIDCEK(){
        formTARIH = [[String]]()
....
 if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                                    for review in baslik {
                                         if let soru_baslik = review["TARIH"] as? String {
                                             let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                                             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                self.formTARIH.append([s])

                                               self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                             } } }  } }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return items.count
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellGecmis", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewTaxCell
        print("article.tarih", article.tarih)

let article = items[indexPath.row]
cell?.altPriceLabel.text = (article.tarih)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're saying `tarih: "\(String(describing: self.formTARIH)`.

`self.formTARIH` is an array — an array of single-element arrays of strings, for some unknown reason.

Well, `[["2020-02-25 22:09"], ["2020-04-25 22:09"], ["2020-04-25 22:09"]]` *is* the string that represents that array. The array has three elements, each of which is an array, each of which contains a date string. So, that's what you asked for and that's what you got.